# Any way to speed this UILabel blur code?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, gaussianblur

Here is the code and it is really slow, like seconds slow to render about 25 labels.

```
extension UILabel{
    func deBlur(){
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if (subview.tag == 99999) {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }

    func blur(){
        let  blurRadius:CGFloat = 5.1

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        blurFilter?.setDefaults()
        let imageToBlur = CIImage(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!)
        blurFilter?.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blurFilter?.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")
        let outputImage: CIImage? = blurFilter?.outputImage
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage!, from: (outputImage?.extent)!)
        layer.contents = cgimg!
    }
}
```

Any image / UIGraphics gurus know why this is so sloooow?

UPDATE: This line of code is the culprit. However, it is also needed to create the blur effect.

```
        let cgimg = UILabel.context.createCGImage(outputImage!, from: (outputImage?.extent)!)
```

Comment: What about putting all the labels in a common view and blurring that one common view instead of each individual label. I don't know if that will give the same result but is certainly should be faster.

Comment: the labels are mostly in a tableview and that would be crazy figuring out which ones to put in the blur view vs. the non-blur view

Comment: I'm out of votes, but this question might be better suited on [coderview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: One easy win would be to share the `CIContext`, which is expensive to create. You could add it as a class property. i.e. `static let context = CIContext(options: nil)`

Comment: definitely faster but still darn slow.

Comment: Very much agree on sharing `CIContext` - that i a costly one. Why are you going from `UIImage` >> `CGImage` >> `CIImage`? From the code you presented, there's no need for that intermediate step. Last and not least, what are the sizes/extents of these images? Yesterday I cleaned up a major performance hit when I downsized my test image from 4096x4096 to 640x640. If you are working with large images, I'll post a `UIImage` extension that can cut it down to anything you want.